# Azure MSI - user assigned identity

Tags: azure

According to this [MSI FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/known-issues) there are some additional features for Azure MSI available only in private preview.
Under this [link to form](https://aka.ms/azuremsiprivatepreview) there's only title "Managed Service Identity - User Assigned Identity"

Does anyone know what are the features? 
I cannot find anything in docs.

Comment: Did you find any further information?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that User Assigned Identity assignments are only available for VM and VMSS as mentioned in [Known issues with User Assigned Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/known-issues#known-issues-with-user-assigned-identities).

Azure Virtual Machines, Azure App Service, Azure Functions, Azure Data Factory V2 supports System Assigned Managed Service Identity. [Reference Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/services-support-msi).

Also note that for now Managed Service Identity (MSI) is a public preview feature of Azure Active Directory.